# Gear cable stuck in Sensah empire shifter mechanism

Tags: shifter, cable

[image]

I was trying to install a new gear cable. However, I messed up by trying to upshift while the cable head was not seated properly. Any ideas of getting the cable out?

Answer (score 2):

You can see the head of the cable.  Try gripping the sides with needlenose pliers and pull it out?

You can also try to free the stuck part using lubricants and penetrating oils.  This will contaminate the rest of the mechanism and its own lubrication, so expect to clean and relube everything after.

Heat is not your friend here - there are too many plastic parts which will be damaged.  Avoid heat.

If the cable is trash, then cut it shorter, perhaps a finger-length still exposed.  The cable is twisted strands of wire.  You may be able to twist the wire such that the cable turns the head and loosens it.  This may mark or damage the internals a bit.     Try using a drill driver to snag the free end  and twist while pushing in.

---

Once you're out of this situation, prevent this from happening again.  Try and identify what went wrong and find a way to stop it repeating.

If the cable's head is too small, use a Shimano-sized cable.  It could be a Campagnolo-sized head which is fractionally smaller.
If the wire is thin, sleeve it with some heatshrink?   Or buy quality shifter cables that are the right size.

Your aim is to recover the shifter mechanism, and saving the cable is less important.

Good luck!